# React Native - Usar camera

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native

Eu gostaria de uma ajuda eu comecei um projeto no qual agora necessito usar a Camera do celular. Criei o projeto com o `create-react-native-app`, porém não consigo encontrar um componente ou solução utilizando puramente JS para utilizar a camera do celular no aplicativo que estou criando.

Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

Já tentei utilizar o componente `react-native-camera`, mas pelo que andei pesquisando e testando ele necessita de código nativo.

Existiria alguma outra solução para que criar o projeto além de ter que cria-lo com a CLI do React Native?

---

EDIT:

[image: Erro React Native Camera]

Não mexi em nenhuma configuração de Android, pois o projeto apenas tem JS. Já que usei o CRNA para criar o projeto.

Comment: Há uma documentação no gitHub explicando como usar o react-native-camera segue o link: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera

Comment: Eu já utilizei da forma que é diata lá e mesmo assim não está funcionando. E o erro que dá já pesquisei e ele está relacionado com o `react-native link`.

Comment: Certo, mas qual é o erro que está dando ?

Comment: poste o erro na sua pergunta e utilize o `react-native-camera` observando bem a documentação, você liberou as configurações no `Android`?

Comment: Editei a publicação para que vejam o erro citado.